# How can I tell if I need a Snap package?

Tags: apt, gnome, dependencies, snap

Just upgraded to 20.04, Focal Fossa, which uses Gnome 3.36, from 19.10. I also have two Snaps of Gnome installed, gnome-3-32-1804 and gnome-3-34-1804. It is unclear to me if these Snaps are actually in-use anymore or if anything is depending on them. I couldn't find anything about dependencies in the snap man page, either. Is this even a thing with Snaps? Do I have to be concerned about dependencies? I'm not actually sure of what installed these two, older Gnome Snaps, either, but I've been cleaning up older snaps because they are conflating with some of my apt-installed packages and the apt packages tend to integrate with the system better, for example respecting theme settings.

Comment: just keep 'em, they won't conflict.

Comment: just delete them, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command

```
snap connections
```

It will show you snaps connected to different interfaces. If a gnome-snap (called extension) is not connected, I think you can delete it.

Comment: This actually answers a lot of questions I've had. It turns out that a Snap package that I rely on (Mattermost) is using the older Gnome Snap. Mattermost is not the most well-behaved application and often has GUI inconsistencies with the rest of the system. Now I have a lead as to why.