kde Snaps occupy too much disc space
I have Ubuntu with Gnome desktop, but I have 15 kde snaps installed, which occupy about 9GB of disc space. How can I rid of them without reistalling system and switching of all snaps?Why do I have all this snaps?
kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20  5.91.0                      1      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20  5.96.0                      7      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20  5.98.0                      9      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20  5.99.0                      7      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-core18               5.67.0                      35     latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18       5.68.0                      4      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20     5.87.0                      8      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20       5.79.0                      14     latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22            5.104                       9      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22            5.105                       11     latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf5-5-106-qt-5-15-9-core22            5.106                       23     latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf5-5-108-qt-5-15-10-core22           5.108                       5      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf5-5-110-qt-5-15-11-core22           5.110                       3      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf5-5-111-qt-5-15-11-core22           5.111                       7      latest/stable    kde✓             -
kf6-core22                            6.6.0                       39     latest/stable    kde✓             -

Snap do not care if I've got enough space. It's take it all. Sometimes gdm fail to start because there is not enough space and I'm forced to manually remove older snaps. Its frustrating

You'll have those snaps because you're installed or used something that required them. Those appear to be Library files (KDE Frameworks) and are not specifically KDE Plasma related; but maybe required by Qt5/6 apps that use the KF5/6 toolkit/library (most KDE Plasma apps do use KDE Frameworks, but not all do).  Use snap list to list what you have installed & ensure you don't have apps that require those.  Maybe useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267967/how-can-i-determine-which-snaps-are-dependencies-and-which-are-manually-install
